# Inverse of an Atomic Lower Triangular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & .. &..  &.. \\
  .. & 1 &..  &.. \\
  .. &l_{k+1,k} &.. &..\\
.. &.. .. &..  &.. \\
  .. &l_{n,k} &.. &1
\end{pmatrix}

the inverse is $L_i*$

\begin{pmatrix}
  1 &..  &..  &.. \\
  .. &.. 1 &..  &.. \\
  .. &-l_{k+1,k} &.. &..\\
.. &.. .. &..  &.. \\
  .. &-l_{n,k} &.. &1..
\end{pmatrix}

how can I show in a nice formal way that indeed $L_i * L_i* = I$?

Comment: Is multiplying the matrices formal enough? You should add $0$'s where they belong. As they are, they don't look like atromic matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a = (0,..,0,l_{i+1,i},..,l_{n,i})$.

Than $$(I + e_i a^T)(I-e_ia^T) = I+e_ia^T e_ia^T$$

But $a^Te_i=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Write $L_i$ as $I + A$, where $A$ is the same as $L_i$ but with all $0$ on the diagonal, and do the same with $L_i^*$. Now it's quite easy:

> $L_i*L_{i}^* = (I+A)(I+A^*) = I + ( A + A^* ) + AA^*$

now, the sum in the brackets is obviously $0$, and the product $AA^* = 0 $ too ( should be quite easy to prove)

Answer (score 0):

More generally, for any block lower triangular matrix of the form
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
I_k&0\\
F&I_{n-k}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
we have
$$
M^{-1}=
\begin{pmatrix}
I_k&0\\
-F&I_{n-k}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
In your particular case,
$$
\quad F=\begin{pmatrix}
0&\ldots&0&l_{k+1,k} \\
0&\ldots&0&0 \\
\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots \\
0&\ldots&0&0 \\
0&\ldots&0&l_{n,k}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$